# WinForm Chart not showing ToolTip

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

The code I have loops through a datagridview based on the column selected and for each value in that row creates a point on a series

This is the code I've tried:

```
       System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series FirstVallSeries = new System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Series
        {
            Name = SelectedColumn + "-" + FilterVal1.Text,
            //   Color = Color.DarkBlue,
            IsVisibleInLegend = true,
            IsValueShownAsLabel = true,


            ChartType = (SeriesChartType)Enum.Parse(typeof(SeriesChartType), ChartTypeComboBox.Text, true),



        };



        foreach (string e in distinctArray)
        {
            for (intRow = 0; intRow < dataGridView1.Rows.Count;)
            {


                if (dataGridView1[SelectedColumn, intRow].Value.ToString() == e)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[SelectedColumn, intRow].Value)) == false)
                    {


                        firstval++;

                    }
                }
                intRow++;
            }

            DataPoint dp = new DataPoint();
            dp.SetValueXY(e, firstval);
            dp.ToolTip = string.Format("{0}, {1}", e, firstval);

            FirstVallSeries.Points.Add(dp);


                   firstval = 0;
```

But when I run the App and mouse over each point in the series within the chart, the tool tip doesn't show up.

I can see the values, but no tooltip.

Comment: The code works fine. You need to wait a little (hover without moving) until they show up. Or show us more about how your points are created. But it looks perfectly fine to me.. What chartype do you use? Hovering __precisely over__ a point is a little hard for Line or Curve charts or even small point makers..

Comment: After i create the series i add it to chart1, which is blank. Ill check the code again, but is there anything i need to enable for the chart1?

Comment: No, every point with a ToolTip will show it automatically. you can also show a Series based ToolTip instead, provided the [chart keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are good enough.. But, no, nothin to enable or add. Do you see the DataPoints? What ChartType do you use __??__

Comment: I used a column chart, then switched to a point chart. Still nothing. The datapoints show up but no tooltip.

Comment: I updated my code, so you can see how I add the points.

Comment: Strange, I don't see a problem. Try to set the ToolTip to a constant for testing : `dp.ToolTip = "TEST";` Don't move over it, stay on it without moving for a while!!

Comment: How long is a while? Ive been on it for about 1 min 30 sec

Comment: Na, ca 1 second will do. But you need to hit the DataPoint. You may try setting the MarkerSize a little larger..: `FirstVallSeries.MarkerSize = 20;`

Comment: Lol idk how or why but this worked. I was on the point for sure and now theyre too big, but the tooltipshows up

Comment: Well you can reduce them to a smaller value to suit your needs..

Comment: I reduces the marker size to 10, nows it not working haha. Thank you though! Ill play around with the size

Comment: Hm, strange; the default is 5 but with a little care I can hit it even at 3 but that is not recommended of course. Do you have a retina display?

Comment: It worked with 10 now, im using visual studio 2015...might have something to do with it

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
dp.ToolTip = "#SERIESNAME : X=#VALX, Y=#VALY";
```

There are a list of special keywords the tooltip understands to get it to display your values (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456687.aspx)).  In your case you probably only care about #VALX and #VALY.  This should make it show up even if you aren't exactly on the marker point.