# Tooltip not showing on VB.NET chart Series set by Databinding

Tags: .net, vb.net, tooltip, mschart

Using VB.NET 4.8.04161. I have a chart that I create from a DataTable, and I'd like to display a tooltip on hover with the Y-Value. I'm setting the tooltip for each series as a whole using the "#VALY" variable. But nothing appears when I hover. To test, I've also added a tooltip to the legend of each series with dummy text, and that also does not show up. Finally I added a tooltip to a Button on the same form as the chart and that works just fine.

I've also looked through the few questions on SO relating to missing tooltips - all were on setting tooltips to specific datapoints, not the series as a whole. One suggested increasing the dp size ([How to display tooltips with various data in MS charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46212740) and [WinForm Chart not showing ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507729)), which seemed to work for the OP. So I increased BorderWidth to 20 (from 3) with no luck.

I also paused execution to make sure that Chart1.series(0).Tooltip had a value. My code is below:

```
            Dim dt as DataTable = <Getting a datatable from a SQL query>
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -45
            Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "c0"
            ToolTip1.ShowAlways = True  'Addded to see if it would help-it did not
            For Each ser As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                If ser.ColumnName <> "DateMonth" Then
                    Dim s As New Series
                    Dim mp As String = ser.ColumnName
                    s.Name = mp
                    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
                    s.BorderWidth = 3
                    s.Points.DataBindXY(dt.Rows, "DateMonth", dt.Rows, mp)
                    s.ToolTip = "#VALY"
                    s.LegendToolTip = "THis isthe legend"
                    Chart1.Series.Add(s)
                End If
            Next
            For Each legend In Chart1.Legends
                legend.Docking = Docking.Bottom
                legend.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
            Next
```

What am I missing for why the tooltip doesn't show on a chart element but works on a form control?

Comment: You mention setting the tooltips of specific datapoints. Does that work, or do they also not show up?

Comment: Have you tested on a clean Chart object, without any settings to ChartAreas and such apart from the defaults?

Comment: I followed this thread and got it to work - first I tried setting tooltip on dp, which didn't work. But then I created a separate loop at the end of the code looping through datapoints, and that did appear. Finally I tested just assigning a tooltip to the series after I had added it to the chart, not before, which also worked. Not sure why - that doesn't match the examples I found but I'll take it

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce your issue in a vb.net 4.8 Windows Forms App.

As a substitute for the datasource I added some dummy data:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable()
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("DateMonth", Type.GetType("System.DateTime")))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Column2", Type.GetType("System.Int32")))

'Add dummy data points, one random integer Y-value per month.
Dim random As New Random
For index = 1 To 10
    Dim row1 As DataRow
    row1 = dt.NewRow()
    row1.Item(0) = New DateTime(2022, 1, 1).AddMonths(index)
    row1.Item(1) = random.Next(1, 10)
    dt.Rows.Add(row1)
Next
```

When running the application the tooltips seem to work fine.
[image]

Would you please test with this same dummy data, and/or show some code that better emulates your own dataset?

Comment: Thanks for the test. I tried with your code and having the same result as before. It makes me think there's something about the chart object itself in my form that is preventing tooltips from appearing inside

Comment: Although I dropped in a new Chart object and tried the code on that and no tooltips either